# Does BigQuery have a "Fill Record" mode for CSV loads with incomplete lines?

Tags: google-bigquery

We've been collecting structured logs from our web application, which outputs a pipe-delimited CSV file.  Over time, we've been adding extra information on the end of the newer information.

For example, our older data has 14 columns and newer data has either 15 or 16 columns.

Is there a flag that can be passed in during load (like "fillrecord") to treat the missing columns on older data as null values?

Answer (score 3):

The feature you're asking for is now available in BigQuery. If you're running bq.py (you'll need the latest version), you can add the `--allow_jagged_rows` flag. If you're using the api directly, setting 'allowJaggedRows' to true in the load configuration should work.